# There is no ViewData in Partial Page Asp.NET IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having a problem trying to load a partial view in the index page, the error that the site displays is the following:

**There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'QuestionType'** basically the problem seems to be in the dropdown html.

Here's my partial:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionType, "QuestionType", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("QuestionType", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuestionType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Question Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.QuestionType = new SelectList(db.QuestionTypes, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: MyQuestions/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Description,QuestionDate,Tags,QuestionType")] MyQuestion myQuestion)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.MyQuestions.Add(myQuestion);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.QuestionType = new SelectList(db.QuestionTypes, "Id", "Name", myQuestion.QuestionType);
        return View(myQuestion);
    }
```

And here is how I call the partial:

```
<div class="modal-body">
            @Html.Partial("_CreatePartial", new MyWebAppInMVC.Database.MyQuestion())
        </div>
```

At the top of the partial I use the following line:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "MyQuestions", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "AddModal" }))
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You’re trying to take QuestionType from model, but it’s in the viewbag (which is a bad practice you should abandon immediately in favor of proper model binding through ViewModels)

Comment: This code was basically generated automatically from Visual Studio.

Comment: But it’s basically wrong, isn’t it? ;)

Comment: Sure it is, what should I do? so, how my code should look like?

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurred because `QuestionType` is a `ViewBag` property and you're not returning any model to the view, also contains potential naming collision because `QuestionType` is already exists as viewmodel property:

```
ViewBag.QuestionType = new SelectList(db.QuestionTypes, "Id", "Name");
return View();
```

And you're not specifying option lists while using `DropDownList` helper:

```
@Html.DropDownList("QuestionType", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The recommended way to provide option lists into dropdown is by creating strongly-typed viewmodel property to hold option lists, as provided in example below:

```
public class MyQuestion
{
    // other properties

    // this property bounds to dropdownlist
    public int QuestionType { get; set; }

    // option list property
    public List<SelectListItem> QuestionTypeList { get; set; }
}
```

Afterwards, modify both controller action and partial view to hold selected value:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var myQuestion = new MyQuestion();

    myQuestion.QuestionTypeList = db.QuestionTypes.Select(x => new SelectListItem 
    {
        Text = x.Name, 
        Value = x.Id 
    }).ToList();
    return View(myQuestion);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(MyQuestion mq)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // process data and redirect
    }

    mq.QuestionTypeList = db.QuestionTypes.Select(x => new SelectListItem 
    { 
        Text = x.Name, 
        Value = x.Id, 
        Selected = (x.Id == mq.QuestionType) 
    }).ToList();
    return View(mq);
}
```

**Partial view**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.QuestionType, Model.QuestionTypeList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuestionType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write your `@Html.DropDownList` as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("QuestionType", ViewBag.QuestionType as SelectList,"Select Question Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Same result. :(

Comment: Problem is View Data that your passing from controller method are unavailable in partial view.